# Simplecv and Android app

Tags: android, tornado, simplecv

I want to make an android app that makes beautiful effects on images using SimpleCV. I found this app http://github.com/victsou/simplecv-mobile-camera

I have windows, and I have installed tornado in my laptop. when I try to test the app  on my android device, the app is not working although I ran the server and I changed the ip address in the app and the server code to my local ip address.

```
http://192.168.1.146:8000
```

The phone and computer are connected to the same network, but the router was not connected to the internet. Also, I tried to connect to the internet and use my public IP address, and it did not work.  Can you help me to know why it s not working,please? Thank you so much.

Comment: Which IP address did you use? Your lan ip, 127.0..., or your computer's public ip address (the ip you see when you visit ipchicken.com)? Are both the phone and computer connected to the same network?

Comment: No I used 192.168.1.146 , and yes both the phone and computer are connected to the same network.

Comment: Please help me..I have to make the app works.

Comment: Also verify on windows that your firewall isn't turned on.

Comment: Thank you Xamox..The server was not working because of the firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Xamox answered,the server was not working because of the firewall. After I disabled the firewall, it worked.